# convert Date to Julian day in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, date, cells, microsoft-excel-2019

How to calculate the fourth column based on the first three columns in Excel?

Date cell to Julian **day**

for example:

```
year  month   day  **Julian day**
2000    1       1      1
2000    1       2      2
2000    1       3      3
....    .       .      .
....    .       .      .
2000     12     30     365
2000     12     31     366
2001     1       1      1
2001     1       2      2
2001     1       3      3
....     .       .      .
....     .       .      .
2001     12      30     364
2001     12      31     365
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this formula: `=DATE(A2,B2,C2)-DATE(A2,1,0)`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Nice one @Lee ☺

Answer (score 0):

This is not the Julian Day. A Julian day is the number of days since the beginning of the Julian period (see
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day).

Comment: This should be a comment.